# Planar Kinematics: Circular orbit?

Tags: dynamical-systems, kinematics

Assuming that the Earth's orbit around the Sun is circular, determine the mass of the Sun. It is also assumed that the mass of the sun is much greater than the mass of Earth. It is known the Earth completes a full orbit in 1 year.

**Attempted Solution**:

I want to do this problem without assuming a value for the radius of Earth's orbit.

Starting point: Kepler's Third Law:
$$T^2 = \left(\frac{4\pi^2}{GM}\right)r^3$$
unknowns: $M$ and $r$

Since the orbit is circular, the speed $v$ is constant. More so, the acceleration is:
$$\mathbf{a}_e = -r \dot{\theta}^2\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$$
from planar kinematics of a circular orbit where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$ is the unit vector that points in the direction of radius to Earth.

Here is where I am stuck unfortunately, I want to use the 2D planar kinematics equations of motion to solve for $r$ which can then be used in Kepler's Third Law to get $M$. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forget the mathematical equations for a second. Why should it be possible to "solve for $r$" without observing its real-world value, even in principle?

Comment: @Caffeine Aren't these informations already contained into Kepler's second law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kepler's second law for circular motion can be obtained by the following equations

- $\omega=\frac{2\pi }T\quad a_c=\omega^2r$
- $ma_c=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$

therefore to obtain $M$ from the second law we need some more information to obtain $r$.

Comment: isn't the second bullet Kepler's third law just in terms of angular velocity? which gives only one equation. I guess my question is if there is a way to relate the kinematics of a circular orbit to Kepler's laws in order to get $M$

Comment: @Clark The Kepler's second law can be obtained from all these equations. To find M we need some more information, that is $r$ or $v$.